# Cannot select vertex

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I made a plane, and added knife cuts - now i cannot select specific vertices. 
See picture below:

[image]

Comment: Could you in future please use the inline image hosting to display image in question.  https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/can-a-punishment-be-implemented-for-using-the-word-vertice-in-a-q-a

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in image uploaded to add images: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have overlapping vertices. That means two or more vertices share the exact same position in 3D space. When you click on one of them, you are actually selecting a vertex, but it doesn't appear like it since one or more are overlapping.

Select all the vertices with the shortcut  <kbd>A</kbd>  (in edit mode) then right click > Merge vertices > By distance.

Comment: Solved the issue, thank you!